# What does "Other" represent when looking at iTunes representation of free space on an iDevice?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

In the graphical space representation of my iPhone, the `Other` category takes a pretty big chunk.

[image]

How can I find out what is in the `Other` category?  If it's text messages from the last 4 years that I've owned iPhones, how can I browse them?

Answer (score 5):

### What is the Other space

On an iPhone, the `Other` storage can be classified as one of the following:

```
    Browser cache
    Mail cache
    Mail messages
    Mail attachments
    Safari's Reading List
    iTunes Backups
    Effects of jailbreaking your iDevice
    Game data
    Saved data files
    Call history
    Notes
    Media
    Voice memos
```

### How to Remove It

Just follow these steps (Check the articles listed below for more information):

1. Delete the browser cache (and Reading Lists in Safari).
2. Delete and re-add your mail account.
3. Remove unimportant text messages.

This will allow you to remove the majority of the extra "stuff" that clogs your space. PhoneClean, referenced below, is a great tool that will do it all for you, so if you just want to remove the most amount of space in the least amount of time, just use that.

### Links and Resources

1. http://appducate.com/2013/01/reclaim-other-storage-space-on-ipad-iphone-and-ipod/
2. http://www.imobie.com/support/what-is-the-other-on-my-iphone.htm
3. http://www.cultofmac.com/133183/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-other-data-stored-on-my-ipad-or-iphone-ask-macrx/

[PhoneClean](http://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/) is some freeware that frees up space by removing hidden files. I can't vouch for its reliability, but I've heard some good things about it, so check it out.

Answer (score -1):

"**Other**" is data on your phone that is not apps, ibooks, photos, music or videos. This means operating system settings and data, Safari cache, Siri cache, downloaded maps, reminders, notes, stocks, weather data, email, texts, imessages, and data for all of the apps on your phone. 1 GB is normal for Other. It can be much larger if you have a lot of apps or have apps that use a lot of data, such as Facebook.

If you want to have a small Other don't install any apps, don't use email, don't save texts, don't use maps...but then why would you have an iPhone in the first place? Other is not a problem; it is what the phone is for.

You can use 3rd party apps like [CleanMyPhone](http://www.fireebok.com/cleanmyphone.html), PhoneClean to remove the data from your device

Resources: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23825850#23825850